# BOSH hadoop-release error

Tags: hadoop, cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

I'm trying to deploy hadoop-release in my BOSH-lite on local VM, while deploying i'm getting `Error while reserving job: PG:: Error: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on 5432?`

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL *appears* not to be running on your BOSH lite. I’d like to check that. Could you please `ssh vcap@192.168.50.4` (password `c1oudc0w`) and type `ss -ltn` and confirm that the postgres port (5432) is bound:

```
LISTEN      0    128                 127.0.0.1:5432        *:*
```

and that postgres is running `ps auxwww | grep postgres`:

```
vcap      1453  0.1  0.1  56728  7344 ? S<   13:30   0:00 /var/vcap/data/packages/postgres/4b9f6514001f7c3f7d4394920d6aced9435a3bbd-6cb375e19ce352db095a4b18cf4c56b2bf9b952f/bin/postgres -D /var/vcap/store/postgres -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432
vcap      1566  0.0  0.0  56728  3368 ? S<s  13:30   0:00 postgres: writer process
vcap      1567  0.0  0.0  56728  2280 ? S<s  13:30   0:00 postgres: wal writer process
vcap      1568  0.0  0.0  57688  4600 ? S<s  13:30   0:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process
vcap      1569  0.0  0.0  19772  3012 ? S<s  13:30   0:00 postgres: stats collector process
vcap      1845  0.0  0.1  58880  9204 ? S<s  13:30   0:00 postgres: bosh bosh 127.0.0.1(36956) idle
```

Comment: Hi, Yes postgres services are running, please have a look at attached image http://pasteboard.co/eoZbT365K.jpg